# Integrate over a meshgrid space

Tags: matlab

Currently I'm working on a project trying to recreate Young's original experiment. To make a long story short, I have a rather complicated surface defined using matlab's meshgrid and I want to evaluate my defined function (fun in the code) over this surface.

My code is currently looking like this:

```
clc;
clear all ;
M = 20 ;
N = 100 ;
R1 = 1 ;  % yttre radien
nR = linspace(0,R1,M) ;
nT = linspace(0,2*pi,N) ;
nx = linspace(-0.1,0.9,N);
ny = linspace(-1,1,M);
%nT = pi/180*(0:NT:theta) ;
[B, Z] = meshgrid(nx,ny);
[R, T] = meshgrid(nR,nT) ;
lambda = 1;
fun= @(s) e^((i*2*pi/lambda)*(1/2 * (cos(lambda/(4*pi*s))/2)));
% Convert grid to cartesian coordintes
X = R.*cos(T); 
Y = R.*sin(T);
[m,n]=size(X);
% Plot grid
figure
set(gcf,'color','w') ;
axis equal
axis off
box on
hold on
for i=1:m
    plot(X(i,:),Y(i,:),'k','linewidth',1.5); 
end
for j=1:n
    plot(X(:,j),Y(:,j),'k','linewidth',1.5); 
    plot(B(:,j),Z(:,j),'b','linewidth',1.5);
end
```

If you try to run my code, I want to evalute the function fun over all the space in the meshgrid except for the blue part, can this be done or should I restart and approach the problem in a different way? Thanks in advance

Comment: what value should s take in your fun?

Comment: I want s to be the radius of my surface, so in this case it should be from 0-1, but I dont want to integrate it over the area that is blue colored.